# Format template string for different code types

Tags: javascript

I've got a component which does this:

```
<CodeBlock language="css" code={`p { color:  hsl(1deg, 100%, 50%)};`} />
```

Inside the component I run Prism.js for code highlighting. This is all good. The problem I have is when the indentation of the general code leads to a situation like this:

```
  <Box>
     <CodeBlock code={`p { 
        color:  hsl(0deg, 100%, 50%);
     }`} language="css" />
  </Box>
```

and lots of extra whitespace gets added.

I want to be able to process and format the strings for whitespace. I can trim the edges of the string but I need to sort indentation. I have looked at i[ndent.js](https://zebzhao.github.io/indent.js/) but that doesn't remove whitespace from the beginning.

Does anyone know how I can solve this?

EDIT (on request):

Current Output:

```css
p { 
        color:  hsl(0deg, 100%, 50%);
     }
```

Required Output:

```css
p { 
  color:  hsl(0deg, 100%, 50%);
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://prismjs.com/plugins/normalize-whitespace/)?

Comment: Just curious:  Why is the hsl missing the close parenthesis?  I see `hsl(0deg, 100%, 50%;` but I was expecting `hsl(0deg, 100%, 50%);` << note the `)`.  Could that be part of the problem?

Comment: @Wyck Just a typo. (Thanks for spotting) The code runs on hundreds of code blocks and has the the same issue. It's because template strings keep all the extra space, so if you indent a template string to align with the external code's indentation you'll end up with extra whitespace in your template string.

Comment: @raina77ow I'd tried that and it didn't work UNTIL I realised that if you return on the first line manually THEN it works. If you have `code={\`p {` then it doesn't trim the space because it reads the first line to find out how big the indent is.

For the record, that is a solution. It just requires me to revisit a few hundred code blocks!! :(

Answer (score 0):

I’ll demonstrate by mimicking the string in a *pre* tag and do the string parsing...

```
<!DOCTYPE html><head></head>

<body onload="Process();">

<script>

function Process(){

let S=Cont.innerHTML;

S=S.replace(/\n+/g,'').replace(/ +/g,'').replace(/{/g,' {\n  ').replace(/;/g,';\n').replace(/:/g,': ').replace(/,/g,', ');

Cont.innerHTML=S;

}

</script>

<pre id="Cont">

p { 
        color:  hsl(0deg, 100%, 50%;
     }

</pre>


</body></html>
```

You start by stripping all spaces and all LFs and then insert them back this time strategically, as desired.

What I’ve done here is compatible with CSS but if your *CodeBlocks* may also contain JS or HTML then you’ll need a separate function to handle each.

I hope you don’t get any mixed *CodeBlocks* because it then gets tricky!